# ASP.NET DataSet outside app_code dir

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I am doing a Web Site in Visual Studio 2010. Actually I'm working on only one module of this page. Module is meant as a subdirectory and all my "module" files must be in this directory. And here comes the problem. I can't use DataSet because i placed it in my subdirectory and not app_code directory.

How can I solve this problem? I was thinking about adding some sort of refernce to Web.config but I don't know how.

Best regards,
Samek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to top of your module page.

```
using System.Data;
```

Comment: this allows me to use DataSet but not my created DataSet1. Thanks anyway.